# My app is saving feedback to firebase but overwriting old feedback

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever a user submit a feedback it get saved in firebase but when a new user or existing user submit another feedback it overwrites in firebase. Please help :) Thanks in advance
I want to add multiple feedback

```
private Firebase ref;
    private EditText username, feedback;

username = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        request = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.request);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this.getActivity());
        ref = new Firebase("firebase url");



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String usernameinput = username.getText().toString();
                String feedbackinput = feedback.getText().toString();
                Firebase Refusername = ref.child("username.");
                Refusername.setValue(usernameinput);
                Firebase Reffeedback = ref.child("request");
                Reffeedback.setValue(requestinput);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please share how your data is modelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

```
ref.child("Feedback").child(username.getText().toString()).child("Name").setValue(username.getText().toString()); 
ref.child("Feedback").child(username.getText().toString()).child("Feedback").setValue(feedback.getText().toString());
```